# Possible to animate side scrolling cards by setting animation position between two states in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, angular-animations

I am trying to find a good way to implement animated card scrolling in Angular 6.  I am using Ionic along with hammer and that part is working fine.  The main issue has to do with how best to use Angular animations.

I want to end up with something similar to what is shown below:

- If the user does a swipe gesture then the code will animate to the next card.
- If the user presses and pans, then the card will move with their finger
- When they release after panning, the code will either animate it back to the center or complete an animation to go to the next card depending upon how far they have panned.

[image]

I have code that can do the swipe animation using a standard Angular animation trigger. (i.e. on swipe event, set animation trigger state to "show-right" or "show-left" and then the animation will start and move/transform the cards)

What I can't figure out how to do is to support the panning.  Specifically using the current pan progress to jump to a point in the animation and when released complete the animation to the new state while starting at the current position.

I have tried using the AnimationBuilder to create a set of animations manually, and this does allow me to control the position of the animation but it doesn't provide a good way to reverse the animation when the user releases if we need to jump back to the center.  So with Animation builder I think I will need to create 4 or more separate animations and manage the state manually along with syncing up positions when jumping from one animation to another.  (swipe-right, swipe-right-reverse, swipe-left, swipe-left-reverse)

I think I can make this work but it will be a pretty ugly hack.

So my questions are:

- Am I missing something obvious about another way to go about this?
- Is there any way (even through a backdoor) to use the Angular state based transitions to tell an animation state:

  - A) to go to a specific position in the animation? (e.g. AnimationPlayer.setPosition())
  - B) to start a state transition animation from a specific point within the animation?
- If I end up with AnimationBuilder, is there any way to "reverse" an animation similar to what the WebAnimations API provides.  (doesn't look like there is so maybe I just need to manually create the reverse animations)

Note: I am holding off on writing up a piece of sample code to share here to duplicate the issue because first I just want to make sure I am even thinking about it correctly.  Sometimes with a sample app I get focused on how to make that specific case work and miss the higher level question of should I even be doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [AnimationBuilder](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationBuilder) to create custom animations dynamically, and keep the sliders position for next movements :

```
constructor(private _builder: AnimationBuilder) { }

moveTo(value) {
  this.position = value;
  this.player = this._builder.build(this.moveXTo(100, value + 'px'))
                .create(this.el.nativeElement, {});
  this.player.play();
}

moveXTo(time: number, to: string): (AnimationStyleMetadata | AnimationAnimateMetadata)[] {
  return [animate(100, style({ transform: 'translateX(' + to + ')' }))];
}
```

[I started a very small example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-slider-beta-angular-animations) that must be improved to be dynamic and responsive.